# Reordenar estrutura HTML via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 300px;" title="" id="Promocoes_chosen">
    <ul class="chosen-choices">

        <li class="search-field">
            <input type="text" value="Selecione" class="" autocomplete="off" style="width: 25px;">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="chosen-drop">
        <ul class="chosen-results">
            <li class="" data-option-array-index="0">1 MÊS GRÁTIS</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">50% ESTUDANTES</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">2 + 1</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">SUPER PROGRESS - CURSOS A DISTÂNCIA</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4">CURSOS GRATUITOS</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="5">SUPER PROGRESS - CURSOS E FORMULÁRIOS</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="6">TABELA PROGRESSIVA DE LIVROS</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="7">50% OFF - AMIGO PAGA MEIA</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="8">50% FIDELIDADE</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="9">CLIENT PLATINUM - Cursos Gratuitos</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="10">Formulário Grátis</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="11">CLIENT GOLD</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="12">AS MAIS CURTIDAS DO FACEBOOK</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="13">%OFF Cursos em Vídeo</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="14">R$0,01 vale muito!</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="15">Formulário Grátis</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="16">Compre 1 Leve 2</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="17">Formulário Grátis</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

O que estou tentando fazer é acrescentar as linhas:

```
<li class="search-choice">
    <span>1 MÊS GRÁTIS</span>
    <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="0">
    </a>
</li>
```

Na seguinte posição

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 300px;" title="" id="Promocoes_chosen">
    <ul class="chosen-choices">
      // EXATAMENTE AQUI //
        <li class="search-field">
            <input type="text" value="Selecione" class="" autocomplete="off" style="width: 25px;">
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Tentei fazer isso utilizando o método `append` mas, sem sucesso.

Comment: Coloca aí o teu append sff, pode ser um erro que tenhas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `append` insere um item no *final* do elemento selecionado, e deveria funcionar pelo que vejo no seu exemplo.

Talvez seu script esteja adicionando mais itens nesse container, e você precise colocar no início? Se for isso, use [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

```
var el = $('<li class="search-field"><input type="text" value="Selecione" class="" autocomplete="off" style="width: 25px;"></li>');   
$('.chosen-choices').prepend(el);
```

Answer (score 3):

Amigo você pode usar a função `append` do jQuery. Por exemplo:

```
$(".chosen-choices").append("<li class='search-choice'><span>1 MÊS GRÁTIS</span><a class='search-choice-close' data-option-array-index='0'></a></li>");
```

Segue uma demonstração [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_append_ref)